# Changing the address a pointer is pointing to in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

Okay, I'm sure this has already been answered here a million of times, but I've been searching the site for some time now and I can't seem to get an answer I'm satisfied with. I'll be glad if you could point me in the direction of a duplicate solved thread about this.

So I have this pointer in C++, `p`, which points to an integer. I make it point to the memory address of this integer `x` whose value is 8. So now `p` stores the memory adress of `x`, which is an integer containing the value 8. So far so good.

Then I have a function `f`, which returns a pointer to an integer in the heap, which value will depend in some way on `p`. I can do `p = f(p);` and it works as expected. Now `p` stores a different memory address. If I print out this address and the content of said address, it shows what I expect it to show.

Here comes the problem. I have another function, `g`, which does essentially the same thing `f` does (I suspect this is what I'm getting wrong, if they did the same thing, both would work the same way). `g` does not return anything, it receives the pointer p and tries to make it point to an integer in the heap, the same way I did with `f` previously, only I'm doing the assignment INSIDE the function.
But now, when printing out the memory address pointed by `p` and the value stored in it, I see that `g` did nothing at all.

So, what's the difference between `f` and `g`? Why is it okay if I perform the assignment outside the function but it's not if I do it inside of it? It looks like in `g` I'm just working with a copy of `p`, a local variable of `g` without affecting the global `p`, but these are pointers, the stored memory address is the same for the global and the local `p`.

Here's the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int* f(int* p);
void g(int* p);

int main() {

    int* p;
    int x = 8;

    p = &x;
    cout << *p << endl;   // -> 8
    cout << p << endl;    // Certain address "A"

    p = f(p);     // prints address "A"
    cout << *p << endl;   // -> 14
    cout << p << endl;    // Different address "B"
    
    delete p;
    
    p = &x;
    cout << *p << endl;   // -> 8
    cout << p << endl;    // Certain address "A"
    
    g(p);         // prints address "A"
    cout << *p << endl;   // -> 14 (why not 65?)
    cout << p << endl;    // Same address "A" (why not a different one?)
    
    
    return 0;
}

int* f(int* p) {
    cout << p << endl;
    int* n = new int(*p + 6);
    return n;
}

void g(int *p) {
    cout << p << endl;
    int* n = new int(65);
    p = n;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter `p` of `g` is declared as pass-by-value, it's copied from the argument, any modification on the pointer itself like `p = ...` has nothing to do with the original argument. The reason is just same as

```
void g(int p) { // p is passed by-value
    p = 65;     // modification has nothing to do with the argument passed
}
```

> the stored memory address is the same

Yes, they both point to the same object. You can modify the object being pointed through the pointer like `*p = ...`.

You can change `g` to pass-by-reference,

```
void g(int *&p) {
    cout << p << endl;
    int* n = new int(65);
    p = n;
}
```

Or pass-by-pointer-to-pointer (and pass the address of pointer to it).

```
void g(int **p) {
    cout << *p << endl;
    int* n = new int(65);
    *p = n;
}
```

Comment: Ohhh, I see. I thought the "p" inside g and the one outside of it were the same because they were storing the same address. I should have been printing &p to see how they're actually different variables. Thank you so much

Comment: @APL2020 Exactly that!

Answer (score 4):

Remember the point you made in paragraph 2. Now extend it a bit. A pointer is a variable that contains an address. If you pass this pointer into a function, whatever `p` points at is passed by reference thanks to `p`, but `p` itself is  passed by value. The `p` inside `g` is a locally-scoped variable that's a copy of the `p` in `main`. Both copies initially store the same address.

Then `p = n;` changes the copy and `main`'s `p` is unaffected.

`g` must accept `p` by reference to be able to update the caller's argument.

```
void g(int *p)
```

must be changed to

```
void g(int * & p)
```